# Music Festival Datasets Resources

Tags: uses-of-open-data, music

I am working on a project right now and I am having a very difficult time finding any open data sets for historical information on american musical festivals or rap concerts. Does anyone know of any great resources that I could use to find data on musical festivals or rap concerts?

Types of data I am looking for include, but are not limited to:

- number of Rap tours per state, season, month, and year
- number of ticket sales per season, per month
- Demographic information around venues such as average age, income, music of interest
- etc..

I would like the data to go back 5 - 10 years.

Comment: Did ypu ever find dqta for this? Ive been looking for the same thing